# Как реализовать такой массив в Pascal? Код прилагается

Tags: javascript, delphi, pascal

Нужно реализовать такую структуру массива на ЯП Pascal.

На JS то, что мне нужно выглядело бы так:

```
//
var treeArr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
//
treeArr[0] = ['A', ['A1', 'A2']];
//
treeArr[0][1][1] = ['A2', ['A2.1', 'A2.2']];
```

Мне предлагают смотреть на многомерные массивы, но я не пойму, как в них создать элемент типа массив.

Допустим, есть:

```
//
var treeArr: array of array of String;
//
SetLength(treeArr, 1);
//
SetLength(treeArr[0], 3);
```

Как присвоить treeArr[0, 1] элемент типа array?

Comment: В примере используется массив из разнородных элементов (и строк, и массивов строк), чего в Delphi нет, за исключением `array of Variant`. Лучше описать, какая задача решается, тогда можно попробовать подобрать языковые средства. Пока это выглядит похожим на что-то типа JSON.

Comment: Типа `array` не существует, может быть тип `array of ..`. Вы объявили `treeArr` как двумерный массив строк, размером 1x3. В каждую ячейку вашего двумерного массива вы теперь можете записать строку: `treeArr[0, 1] := 'A2';`. Если вам нужен трёхмерный массив (судя по примеру кода на js), то вам надо выполнить такое объявление: `treeArr: array of array of array of String;` и добавить его инициализацию  `SetLength(treeArr[0, 1], 2);`. После этого, вы сможете присваивать строковые значения элементам массива: `treeArr[0, 1, 0] := 'A'`.

Comment: ´Как присвоить treeArr[0, 1] элемент типа array?´ для этого он должен быть такой var treeArr: array of array of array of String; потом присваеваешь SetLength(treeArr[0, 1], 3); тогда у тебя будет в treeArr[0, 1] массив из 3 элементов